# Error when trying to use textapi.sentiment in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, fetch-api

I keep receiving this error

> Error: Authentication failed   at IncomingMessage.<anonymous>

And this is snippet of my code in the server.js file :

```
var aylien = require("aylien_textapi");
var textapi = new aylien({
    application_id: process.env.API_ID,
    application_key: process.env.API_KEY
});
app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
    textapi.sentiment({
        text: 'John',
    }, function (error, response) {
        if (error === null) {
            res.status(200).send(response)
        } else {
            console.log(error)
        }
    });
})
```

I have added the app id and key correctly but the response is always Authentication failed, didn't find an answer so far so had to create a question for it,
and I use this code on client side to trigger the server response:

```
fetch('http://localhost:8081/test')
    .then((res) => {
        console.log(res)
        return res.json()
    })
    .then(function (data) {
        console.log(data)
        document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = data.message
    })
```

==Edit==
I also tried running that API request on client side and got that error on chrome console:

> Access to fetch at 'https://api.aylien.com/api/v1/sentiment' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
> api.aylien.com/api/v1/sentiment:1 Failed to load resource:
> net::ERR_FAILED
> localhost/:1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch

Comment: Check console.log the process.env.API_ID and Key to see if they are correct before pass to the object.

Comment: Also, you should not use if (error === null) because error may be undefined. You can use if(error) console.log(error) else send response

Comment: Keys are correctly set yup i even checked it in several stages of the code

Comment: Did you try my second comment above?

Comment: The error === null one can be modified but that's not the issue, i already have an error printed out on console that is "Error: Authentication failed at IncomingMessage.", i wanna know how to solve that error

Comment: One suggestion: try to use postman to test the api with your id and key before use this library. If postman works, it means this library got something wrong and I found that the last update of this library is 3 years before. Maybe there is some updates  miss in between this 3 years

Comment: Also, the cors error happens because your backend doesn’t allow cors and if you are using express, you can install a cors middleware.

Comment: I have cors installed yup
var cors = require('cors')
const app = express()
app.use(cors())

Comment: Check if your backend can run properly with postman first.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235475/discussion-between-criminalduck-and-ikhvjs).